# firebase get recently added snapshot value (only one)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to retrieve only one recently added child value from firebase without timestamp comparision?

I want to get the same key/value (only one child, not full array of child nodes) on the client side while adding it through my firebase console.

```
{users:
   "id-ue3": "bob",
   "id-om4": "john", // <-- recently added
   "id-ker": "kevin" 
}

firebase.database().ref().on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {
   ....
   console.log(last_name); // output --> "john"
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible without a timestamp - to the best of my knowledge, Firebase doesn't have a "retrieve most recently added child" feature.  You need to store a timestamp within each child when the child is added, then build a query to order by the timestamp and limit it to the most recent timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way in your JSON to know what data was most recently added. Since the Firebase Realtime Database doesn't keep any metadata about when data was added, you'll need to include the necessary information in your JSON.

Two ways to do that:

1. Add a timestamp property to your data. You can either use the client-side time for this, or [let Firebase generate a server-side timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps) when it writes the data into the database.
2. Encode the necessary information in the key of the items by adding them with `push()`. For more on these IDs, see this [blog post about push IDs](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html).

Note that you'll likely need to listen to the `child_added` event. The `child_changed` event only fires when you update a child node, not when you add a new child node.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that there is some internal metadata and api implementation fot this... If the opportunity to generate timestamp by firebase during node setting or to auto-increment an id of a node? I mean not by php or js. The functional is very poorly described :(